# Two DIV backgrounds with different sizes

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-size

Essentially, the title says it all all.

```
div {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: url(IMAGE1.PNG), url(IMAGE2.PNG);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), inset 1px 1px 2px #fff, inset -1px -1px 1px #777;
}
```

Essentially, I want image1 to maintain default properties as the typical background, but I want image2 to be set to something equivalent to `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for it perhaps so we can better understand what you are upto?

Comment: Explain the problem and don't refer to the title. Maybe you can add also some html code. and I think you have to give both images a seperate class and add the different css to the classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`background-size` accepts multiple values too.

```css
background-size: auto, cover;
```

```js
var pattern = Trianglify({
  height: 300,
  width: 300,
  cell_size: 40,
});

var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

div.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/955qe.png'), url('" + pattern.png() + "')";
```

```css
div {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), inset 1px 1px 2px white, inset -1px -1px 1px #777;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto, cover;
  height: 140px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trianglify/0.2.0/trianglify.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: Ah, so long as it follows the order of the values stated in background-image, I take it. I was thinking there'd be a trick in the shorthand.

Comment: @RosenJanus: Yep. Also, there’s a demo with triangles, if you like triangles.